# Why PreferenceCategory's title & checkBox color is so light & how can I change it?

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-preferences

I'm developing a material design app & I have declared a xml file for Settings option. I have done this task successfully, but after running & opening the SettingsActivity from menu, it is appearing like this:

[image]

**The problem here is that the title which is 'Notification' & the checkBox's color is very light making them difficult to be seen.**

**Here's `SettingsActivity.java` file's code**:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Settings");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Roboto-Medium.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();

    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        public static final String SHARE_APP_PREFERENCE_KEY = "pref_key_share_app";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        }

        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                              String key) {
            if (key.equals(SHARE_APP_PREFERENCE_KEY)) {
                // do something
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Here's `activity_settings.xml` file's code**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.xxx.abc.SettingsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here's `settings.xml` file's code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="prefNotification"
        android:title="@string/prefNotification">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:id="@+id/prefNotifyCheckBox"
        android:dependency="prefNotification"
        android:key="prefNotify"
        android:summary="@string/pref_notify_summary"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

As I'm new to Android Development, I'm unable to figure out the problem here.

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `accent ` colour for your theme? I have a hunch `PreferenceFragment` pulls in the colour for titles and checkboxes from whatever your `accent` colour is.

Comment: @PPartisan Yes, it is using the accent colour. How can I change it?

Comment: Try creating a custom theme, then setting it in `onCreate()` of your `PreferenceFragment` with `getActivity().setTheme(R.style.your_theme_name)` - if it works I'll type it up as an answer.

Comment: @user5289749 great question. i was also struggling with something related to this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PreferenceFragment` uses the value stored in `colorAccent` of your app's theme to style widgets and titles by default. To resolve it, create a custom theme in your `styles.xml` file, and set the `colorAccent` attribute to an alternate colour:

```
<style name="theme_name" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/another_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yet_another_color</item>
</style>
```

To apply it to your `PreferenceFragment`, call `getActivity().setTheme(R.style.theme_name)` in `onCreate()` of your `PreferenceFragment`.

Comment: This changed the colour but now text or `android:summary="@string/pref_notify_summary"` is gone.

Comment: @HammadNasir Possibly because the text colour needs to be set as well, possible with the `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorSecondary` attributes. Or, you could change the parent theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: man, you have helped me a lot. i had tried to use a custom checkbox by setting `android:widgetLayout="@layout/custom_checkbox"` but it was appearing bad since at the bottom of my custom checkbox background,the color value in colorAccent was being included to style `CheckBoxPreference` . but with your answer, it appeared good.

Comment: Which android attribute is responsible for the colour of the unchecked checkboxes in `MultiSelectPreference` coz in my case the unchecked checkboxes do not show but when selected they take the colour `colorPrimary`

Comment: Figured it out, `MultiSelectPreference` implements `DialogPreference`, so if you have a custom dialog theme you need to ensure that you set `colorControlNormal` to override what you have set in your `AppTheme`